# Adding a package to an iOS app extension Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package

How can I add a package dependency that's already added to my main app to an app extension (for example a `WidgetKit` extension)?

I searched for this answer for a while, so it might save people some time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the target you want to add the package to
2. Under the `General` tab > `Frameworks and Libraries`, click the `+` icon
3. Select the package you want to include